# Different state objets in React class component?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am trying to use a functional component in a class component and I cant make it work.
[Documentation states that there should be two different state object.](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states)

```
The component has two states that can be controlled:

    the "value" state with the value/onChange props combination. This state represents the value selected by the user, for instance when pressing Enter.
    the "input value" state with the inputValue/onInputChange props combination. This state represents the value displayed in the textbox.
```

How can I write it as a class component?

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : 'null'}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my solution. As you can see there is no default value for a class component, unlike in the functional example.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';


export class ControllableStates2 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const symbols = [
            'BTCUSDT',
            'ETHUSDT'
        ];
        this.state = {
            value: symbols[0],
            inputValue: '',
            options: symbols
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{`value: ${this.state.value !== null ? `'${this.state.value}'` : 'null'}`}</div>
                <div>{`inputValue: '${this.state.inputValue}'`}</div>
                <br/>
                <Autocomplete
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                        this.state.value = newValue;
                    }}
                    inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
                    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                        this.state.inputValue = newInputValue;
                    }}
                    id="controllable-states-demo"
                    options={this.state.options}
                    style={{width: 300}}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined"/>}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. But the question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve in both? Whats the error or issue?

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake was in these parts

```
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                        this.state.value = newValue;
                    }}
```

should be

```
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                        this.setState({...this.state, value: newValue});
                    }}
```